# Count frequency of specific value in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object, counter, frequency

I have a JavaScript object that is structured as such:

`var subjects = {all: "inactive", firstSingular: "active", secondSingular: "inactive", thirdSingular: "active", firstPlural: "inactive", secondPlural: "inactive", thirdPlural: "inactive"`

I would like to count the instances of the "active" value within this object (i.e return 2). I could certainly write a function that iterates through the object and counts the values, though I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this (in 1 line) in JavaScript, similar to the collections.Counter function in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const subjects = { all: "inactive", firstSingular: "active", secondSingular: "inactive", thirdSingular: "active", firstPlural: "inactive", secondPlural: "inactive", thirdPlural: "inactive" };

const count = Object.values(subjects).reduce((total, value) => value === 'active' ? total + 1 : total, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Another solution using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) instead of reduce:

```js
const subjects = { all: "inactive", firstSingular: "active", secondSingular: "inactive", thirdSingular: "active", firstPlural: "inactive", secondPlural: "inactive", thirdPlural: "inactive" };

const count = Object.values(subjects).filter(value => value === 'active').length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: another possible solution with filter... .length

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution using `filter` and getting length of result

```js
var subjects = {all: "inactive", firstSingular: "active",secondSingular:"inactive", thirdSingular: "active", firstPlural: "inactive",secondPlural: "inactive", thirdPlural: "inactive"}

var res = Object.values(subjects).filter((val) => val === 'active').length

console.log(res)
```